# jquery add new property to css function

Tags: jquery, css, properties

Is there some way to adding new property name to css in jquery ?
Something like transit which have a lot of new properties (duration,complete etc )
$o I need some like this:

```
var css_class ={
  class1 : {height:100,background:'#000'},
  //class2 ... etc
}
var my_property = function(value){
  $(this).css(css_class.value);
}

$('#element').css({
  width: '100px',
  my_property: 'class1'
});
//expected ... #element have width 100 also height and backround from class1
//I know it can be solved with a plugin like :
// .css(...).my_plpugin('my_property') but I dont want this
```

Thank you.

EDITED: Because more people answer what I try with this? I have added more details in the example.
Maybe mi example is not correct or can be solved in other way (no doubt) but the clearest question is: How the transit plugin (for example) have also other properties? (other than those of css) what is the mechanism (the way) to do this ?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not `.each(function(){})` ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I understand what you say and it is right, but I need strict something like in the example and not anoter way to solve this. So I need  the name of the property inside the css.

Comment: If you express better what you're trying to do then maybe we will be able to help you.

Comment: why don't you just do `addClass()`

Comment: like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/3y93rz46/

Comment: @DaniP Because 1. the css can be dinamic ( variable and operation values contains) 2. Is one experiment for this i don't  want also one plugin.
I dont know if you know the transit plugin  but for example i need to knowing how them are new properties names. Sorry for mi english

Comment: CSS can be dynamic... But it's way more complicated than what you actually try. But you may look for SASS or LESS.

Comment: Now I see your fiddle ... and is very nearly. The last question ... can combine traditional css with them ? .. ( I will I'll try )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have added one condition of jquery source is not a professional solution but it work:

```
//I found this line in jquery source
//style: function( elem, name, value, extra ) {

//I added here mi condition
if(name[0] == '.'){
  var my_class_name = name.substr(1);
  $(elem).css(css_class[my_class_name]);
}
```

So now in mi js code i can write like this:

```
$('#element').css({
  width: '100px',
  '.class1': '', //the empty value for not throw errors 
  //... more css here ...
});
//now the #element have width 100px, height 100px and a black background
```